# How to control and rotate storage data at elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, rotation, storage, logstash

Could you help me ? 
I want to use logstash + elasticsearch + kibana for userfriendly mapping logs. Explain me please.
I can't understand where does elasticsearch store data (for example my logs) and how I can rotate it?

Answer (score 13):

Elasticsearch stores it's data in a way that you can't modify outside of the Elasticsearch API.  Data that goes in from logstash typically goes into a date-stamped index (ie `logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}`).

You can use [Elasticsearch Curator](https://github.com/elastic/curator) to have it delete indexes older than a certain number of days.  The documentation shows this example:

```
curator --host localhost delete indices --older-than 30 --time-unit days --timestring '%Y.%m.%d'
```

---

For `curoator` with version 5.7.6, you should run command with the *Singleton Command Line Interface* mode as below:

```
curator_cli --host elasticsearch delete_indices --filter_list '{"filtertype":"age","source":"name","direction": "older","timestring":"%Y.%m.%d","unit":"days","unit_
count":30}'
```

ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.7/singleton-cli.html

which would connect to Elasticsearch on the current node and delete any index older than 30 days.

Comment: latest versions of curator have replaced all command line parameters with a config file, check the documentation for the correct yaml to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your logs should be stored at

```
PATH_TO_UNZIPPED_ES/elasticsearch/logs/*
```

Reference: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/logging.html

ES data is stored at the same path, but in the /data directory. You will find your indices there